# MongoDB 4.4 / Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-buster

I am trying to install `MongoDB 4.4` on a `Raspberry Pi 4 model B` running `Raspberry Pi OS 64 bits`.

I would like to know the proper way to add the depository:

```
https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/buster/mongodb-org/4.4/
```

I believe it should be inserted in this folder:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

But I can't find the correct manner to do it.
I tried a few options, one being creating a file mongodb-org-4.4.list in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory containing this:

```
deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/ buster main
```

But nothing worked. I always get some error message when running:

```
apt update
```

Something like:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

........

Further information:

If I set the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list to:

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.4 main
```

as recommended in the document [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Debian](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/).

This is the result of running `apt-get update` :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                      
Ign:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease        
Hit:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.4 Release          
Hit:6 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

If someone knows how to solve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Follow instructions in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/, specifically the part about adding keys.

There are no prebuilt packages for arm on Debian. https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive does provide arm64 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thanks, this information is helpful. But then I hit another problem, probably due to the specifics of Raspberry Pi. I edited my post to report on that.

Comment: Updated suggestions

Comment: Yes, in the mean while I did an installation using Ubuntu server. I was also thinking using these packages to make it work on Raspberry Pi OS. I will try that later also following your last indications. Hoping something will work.

Comment: Do Ubuntu packages for ARM64 work on Debian Buster for Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspberry Pi OS 64)? Or did you end up installing amd64 packages on your ARM System? Some clarification is welcome :)

Comment: If you are lucky, yes. Generally, no. amd64 on arm will surely not work at all.

Comment: I think I either typoed or otherwise mistook something with the amd64 links.