# How to install mongodb on a Rspberry PI 4?

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to install mongodb on my Raspberry PI 4 model B running Debian 11.3.

First i tried to install it using apt-get by running the command `sudo apt-get install mongodb` but it result with the following error: **E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate**.
After reading mongodb docs i found that it's a known issue and it's because the mobogdb package provided by Debian is not maintained by MonboDB Inc.

The second way i tried was from MongoDB docs https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/
Those are the steps from the tutorial:

1. Import the MongoDB public GPG Key using the command `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
2. Add the MongoDB repository to apt soruces list file using the command `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/5.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`
3. Run the command `sudo apt-get update`
   and got:

```
    Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
    Ign:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease
    Ign:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease
    Get:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease [15.0 kB]
    Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x bullseye InRelease
    Err:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 13.226.2.64 443]
    Hit:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/5.0 Release
    Reading package lists... Done
    N: Ignoring file 'mongodb-org-4.0.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
    E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

4. Finally - Install mongodb with `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`.

After complete all these steps i've got the error: **Unable to locate package mongodb-org**.

I have seen that this issue has been raised here before but i have not found a solution there.
[MongoDB 4.4 / Raspberry Pi 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231119/mongodb-4-4-raspberry-pi-4)

I would like to get any assistent or referrences that could help me solving this issue.

Comment: What are the messages returned from `sudo apt-get update`?  Please update your question with the info.

Comment: I suggest you that use docker in raspberry-pi4:
https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/docker-tutorial/raspberry-pi-docker
and then create a container from mongo images:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo
and then you can use: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express 
To controlling your MongoDB database,,
Tell me if you have any problems with the configuration, I can guide you to use docker in raspberry-pi4

Comment: or if you want, i can answer this question with docker configuration in raspberry-pi4, thanks

Comment: Thany you for your response. As far as you know there is no another option but only with docker? If does, an answer with docker configuration is fine by me.

Comment: It looks like the RP is running bullseye, but it also looks like MongoDB currently only has up through buster.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes. The RP is runinng bullseye. Are you sure that MongoDB is runinng only with buster? can i get a refernce to this? Thank you.

Comment: Not just buster, but buster is the most recent. http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/

Comment: @TaherFattahi You think you could answer the question with the docker configuration?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I used the latest version form the Raspberry PI imager (from their site). Shouldn't it the rwcommended one? Do you know about benefits with the other versions? Thank you.

Comment: @Michael_Sabbah sorry man- I was very busy - but I answer it now

Comment: @Michael_Sabbah Yes, I would think bullseye is recommended.  I don't know why MongoDB doesn't provide packages for it yet.  I compile everything from source for my Fedora system, and you could do it for your system too, but it is a very long (and large) compile for `mongod`.  All the other tools compile relatively quickly.

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs. I will think i will try first the docker solution.

Comment: Unofficial binaries of recent releases can be found [here](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries).

Answer (score 1):

At the first, you need to install Docker engine on Raspberry Pi 4.
Following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade   
sudo reboot
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo bash get-docker.sh
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
sudo reboot
docker version
```

To create MongoDB container plz give me your O/S version name running on your Pi 4 and then I update this answer... 
anyway you can run this command:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/data:/data/db --name mongo mongo:bionic
```

try this command for arm64:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/data:/data/db --name mongo arm64v8/mongo
```

plz check this link:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/?&_ga=2.245956420.1199726907.1655734879-88534791.1655618178#arm64

Comment: Thanks for the details response. The OS version name is 'Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)'.

Comment: your welcome, a 64-bit distro is definitely required,, i think you running 32 bit OS,,
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on ARM64 is a supported platform for MongoDB 4.2.
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Comment: I am runinng armhf ao it's 32 bit OS. You're saying that i have to change it to 64 bit?

Comment: First try this solution: https://hub.docker.com/r/andresvidal/rpi3-mongodb3:                Start it at Run section

Comment: Docker is not a must.

Comment: I am not saying your answer doesn't help, but its incomplete or simply sounds like the only method is Docker here. As your whole steps mainly focusing on Docker and installating with MongoDB. Perhaps you could have also provide an alternative without the use of Docker.

Comment: @Marcell plz read more about docker and the whole solution about installing MongoDB on Raspberrypi, and read my answer, you can setup MongoDB with this solution --- I suggest a method, and everyone here can suggest their own method, you can write your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can find cross-compilation instructions and unofficial MongoDB binaries on Github [here](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries).

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a Raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu-22.04.2 and I managed to get a proper installation with mongodb.

System update :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Required installation of libss1.1 before installing mongodb :

```
sudo wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18_arm64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18_arm64.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Installing mongodb :

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=4.4.8 mongodb-org-server=4.4.8 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.8 mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.8 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.8
```

Checking the installed version :

```
mongod --version
```

Launch of mongod :

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

If it is well launched you can block the version of mongodb in 4.4.8 :

```
sudo apt-mark hold mongodb-org*
```

End

Answer (score 0):

I installed MongoDB on Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit (Raspberry Pi 4 model B) by this tutorial: https://linuxhint.com/install-mongodb-raspberry-pi/ and it worked for me.

If you have original SD card, there is probably preinstalled 32-bit Raspberry Pi OS. But MongoDB doesn't have 32bit packages for ARM architecture, so you need to install 64-bit operating system. I used "Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit)" (https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/) which should be based on Debian 11. But MongoDB doesn't have Debian packeges for ARM 64 architecture, so I used Ubuntu package...

In terminal:

```bash
# update packages
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

# add GPG key for MongoDB
$ wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# add MongoDB repository
$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list

# update source list
$ sudo apt update

# install MongoDB
$ sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Comment: according to the documentation, the official binaries require a newer instruction set that what is available on the Pi....
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-and-the-pi-4-on-ubuntu-64-bit-aka-armv8-0-a-support/220635